# position:fixed inside of an iframe

Tags: css, iframe

For some reason, if I load an html page that has position:fixed on something, but I load it in an iframe, the fixed positions to not seem to render as fixed, but look more like absolute positioning.

I'm not expecting the fixed divs to be fixed relative to the parent document. I would just think that they would be fixed in the iframe. Is this not possible in an iframe?

Comment: you need to post your code... but fixed positioning is like absolute positioning if the element is within another element like an iframe. Does your iframe scroll?

Comment: Yes, the iframe scrolls.

Answer (score 9):

Chrome has a bug that doesn't fix elements with `position:fixed` if:

a) you use CSS3 transform in *any* element, and/or

b) you have a child element positioned outside the box of it's parent element

Oddly enough, the bug was reported back in 2009 and it's still open: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574

Comment: Interestingly, I've spotted this bug in Firefox too

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be fixed to the `iframe` based off this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ww9mK/6/ (note: jsfiddle uses an `iframe` and my height's and width's were just to test scrolling).

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS Mobile devices though.  I'm currently supporting iframe for a client, and the `position:fixed` doesn't work for iPhones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is similar question [fixed vertical positioning of css within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574795/fixed-vertical-positioning-of-css-within-an-iframe)

It looks like there is no problem with position fixed to be fixed to the iframe. Example: http://digitaldreamer.net/media/examples/iframe-site.html

Can you provide code you are working on?